# Setting the Time and Date via Python/Linux

Tags: python, linux

I am developing an inventory control system that will hopefully be deployed within several of our plants. I am going to be using a Linux SBC (Pi, Beaglebone......etc.) platform. I want my user interface to be non-Linux so that the end user does not need to know the Linux OS or how to navigate using the command line. My app will auto-launch at boot and provide the end user with all the necessary front end with a Python/Tkinter HMI. My prototype is based on the Raspberry Pi B. Because many of the installations may not have a network available I need a way to set the system time thru the user interface via python. I am using a Dallas 3231 RTC I2C chip on the GPIO pins with the i2C interface. Everything is worked out except there does not seem to be a simple way for Python to set the system time, write it to the RTC, and ignore the NPT sync if a network is available. This may be super simple, but I am stumped.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-date-time-from-linux-command-prompt/ , and use `os.system` ... but you will need to be root(or sudo)

Comment: Do you _really_ need to handle the system's behaviour regarding time in Python? You can configure your OS to use the RTC instead of NPT. And if there's an NTP source available, why would you ignore it? The common approach is to use it and sync to the hardware clock afterwards/on shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

Someone might come up with something better, but here's how I've done it in the past.

```
import subprocess
import datetime

try:
    subprocess.check_call("ntpdate") #Non-zero exit code means it was unable to get network time
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    dt = getRTCTime() # Get time from RTC as a datetime object
    subprocess.call(['sudo', 'date', '-s', '{:}'.format(dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))], shell=True) #Sets system time (Requires root, obviously)

#Rest of code
```

Comment: `shell=True` is generally incorrect when you pass a list to `subprocess`.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar situation with Raspberry Pi 4 where I wanted to update the system time based on some input.

```
import time

def update_time(unix_time_as_string):
    clk_id = time.CLOCK_REALTIME
    time.clock_settime(clk_id, float(unix_time_as_string))
```

In my example, `unix_time_as_string` comes from a web interface and is something like '1581084210.006'.

Comment: This works well for my use. However, I noticed while running this code that the Raspberry Pi 4 will revert quickly back to NTP time if you are connected to the internet, so it doesn't fit the OP's constraint of ignoring the NTP sync. (Using RaspiOS Bullseye x64.)